# Angular unit test vs integration test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, testing

I've recently started writing unit tests for angular app I'm working on.
There is one thing that I'm not sure about and that's a difference between unit test and integration test in context of Angular.

Assuming that I have a controller to test which depends on another (non angular) service, should I create a mock of a service or try to use real service when it's possible.

If I inject the service itself doesn't that mean I'm creating an integration test instead of a unit test?

I'm asking about that because my work colleagues keep writing tests that inject real servicesand still call them unit tests. It sucks big time especially when you have to debug errors from injected services in tests and each service depends on 5 other services...

Comment: In my experience, angular's tests (jasmine/mocha) involve inject 'real' services BUT your unit tests would 'stub' their behavior with whatever interaction that is desired.  You could use `$provide` to mock these dependencies as a whole but usually when you multiple things needed of a service, its just easier to inject the real thing and use 'stub's to just define your test's behavior.  The biggest enemy to unit tests is 'state' inside a service and you need to maintain as little as possible of that inside of a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of a unit test is to verify underlying unit's behavior in isolation from the environment and other units. Essentially, if your system under test, or the test itself, interacts with external systems, this is not a real *unit* test.

A couple of months ago I have written an [article](http://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters) about this topic. Check it out for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Your anwer was really helpful and it confirmed what I was thinking. Also, really cool and interesting article.